# What type of class of datetime fields in laravel

Tags: laravel, class, datetime

When I fetch data from database using Laravel, I got some timestamp field like 'created_at', 'updated_at',....
What type of class for these fields, what type of class which return `true` of expression `$created_at instanceof DatetimeClass`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent Laravel uses ([Carbon library v2](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/))
for that type of data ([Illuminate\Support\Carbon](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Carbon.html)).

As for `... instanceof DatetimeClass` part of your question, I am not sure what really you refer to as `DatetimeClass` class, but I assume that you meant built-in `DateTime` class. If that's so, you can get `DateTime` from Carbon object by calling `toDateTime()`, i.e.:

```
$dt = $model->created_at->toDateTime();
```

Alternatively, edit your `... instanceof ...` uses to test against Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

Please also have a look at date mutators in Laravel. Laravel will automatically cast a timestamp(created_at, updated_at) or when you need to define custom date fields in the db you can define these in the model: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

If you do not want to automatically cast you can parse a string representation of a date using `$carbonObject = Carbon::parse('2020-02-03');`